# Hibernate inserts extra records in the database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am working on a simple application built using `Spring MVC`, `JSP`, `Hibernate`, and `MySQL`.

I have two entities: `User`, and `UserDetail`.

**User**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "name")
    @NotNull(message = "required field")
    @Size(min = 3, message = "should contain at-least 3 characters")
    private String name;
    
    @Column(name = "salary")
    @NotNull(message = "required field")
    @Min(value = 0, message = "should be a valid positive number")
    private int salary;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Valid
    private List<UserDetail> addressList;
    
    ...
}
```

**UserDetail**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_detail")
public class UserDetail {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "address")
    @NotNull(message = "required field")
    @Size(min = 5, message = "should contain at-least 5 characters")
    private String address;
    
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {
        CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE,
        CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH}
    )
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    ...
}
```

There is a `one-to-many` relation between `User` and `UserDetail` entities - a single user can have multiple addresses.

There is a form on the frontend which contains following fields:

- name
- salary
- address (could be multiple addresses, user can add more input fields using a button)

Upon submission of a form from the frontend, i validate the form data and once it is determined that form data is valid, i call a method that inserts the data in the `MySQL` database.

#### Problem

When the form is submitted with only one address, data is saved in the database correctly.

Problem is when the form is submitted with more than one address. For example, if the form is submitted with two addresses, data is inserted in the `user` table correctly BUT in the `user_detail` table, instead of inserting two records, 3 records get inserted.

Following is the screenshot of the `user_detail` table with incorrect data:

[image]

In the above screenshot, user with the id of 1 has two addresses but there are three rows inserted and the middle one is not associated with the user, i.e `user_id` is `null`.

Following image shows the sql statements logged by the hibernate on the console:

[image]

Following screenshot shows the data inserted in the `user_detail` table if there are 3 addresses in the submitted form data:

[image]

"test address 2" and "test address 3" are duplicated.

Following image shows the sql statements logged by the hibernate on the console:

[image]

Following method is used to insert the data:

```
public static void saveUserData(User user) {
    SessionFactory factory = new Configuration()
                                .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                                .addAnnotatedClass(User.class)
                                .addAnnotatedClass(UserDetail.class)
                                .buildSessionFactory();
    
    Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
    
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        
        session.save(user);
        
        UserDetail userDetail;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < user.getAddressList().size(); i++) {
            userDetail = user.getAddressList().get(i);
            userDetail.setUser(user);
            
            session.save(userDetail);
            
            // hibernate batch insert
            // 10 --> hibernate's batch size
            if (i % 10 == 0) {
                session.flush();
                session.clear();
            }
        }
    
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        
    } catch (HibernateException | ConstraintViolationException e) {
         if (session.getTransaction() != null) {
             session.getTransaction().rollback();
         }
         
         System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage()); 
    } 
    finally {
        session.close();
        factory.close();
    }
}
```

#### Question

Why is hibernate inserting an extra record in the `user_detail` table? How can i fix this issue?

**Versions:**

- `Spring (5.3.4)`
- `Hibernate (5.4.29.Final)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need the batch insert there? It doesn't work at all regarding logs! You have to add an additional parameter to a database URL and enable it for Hibernate.

**Without batch insert**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "USERS")
    public class User {
        
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "ID")
        private Long id;
        
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
        private List<UserDetail> userDetails = new ArrayList<>();
        
        @Transient
        public void addUserDetail(UserDetail detail) {
            detail.setUser(this);
            userDetails.add(detail);
        }      


    }
    
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "USER_DETAILS")
    public class UserDetail {
        
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private Long id;
        
        
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
        private User user;
    
    }
```

```
for each userDetail
    user.add(userDetail)

save(user);
```

So just save a user.

1. Use plurals for table names
2. Use uppercase for table names
3. Use `Long` for id (so it can be null)
4. Use `orphanRemoval`
5. Don't use cascade at the `@ManyToOne`
6. Use `fetch = FetchType.LAZY` everywhere

**With batch insert**

Check that `User` doesn't have details at all

Save user

Set user for each detail

And save details with batch

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I solved the problem by getting just calling the `setUser` setter inside the loop and only saving the `User`. But i am still not sure _what_ exactly caused the issue? I still have cascade on `@ManyToOne`, so that doesn't seems to be the cause of the issue. (It's been around 10 days since i started with hibernate, so lots of things about it don't yet make sense to me.)

Comment: @Yousaf Maybe that cascade doesn't matter. Maybe it worked when you did `session.save(userDetail)`. I doin't use all those cascades at all. So I am not sure :)